# Javascript File Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript file on two websites:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
```

It works fine on one but I get the following error in Chrome Console on the other:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>   at ekko-lightbox-init.min.js:1
>
> ContentScript.js:112 Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined

I can't see any other major differences between to the two websites.

Comment: did u include jquery'

Comment: It uses jQuery, you have to load the library before the script.

Comment: The error says `TypeError: $ is not a function`, not `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. So what is `$`? Use your console to find out.

Comment: @ild flue yes I did

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not come with javascript natively. you need to import it like you would any library.

Comment: It is before the script

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a different version of jquery. It works now.